# getLastRow() doesn't work correctly in my script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok so this doesn't work:

```
var range = mainList.getRange(1, 1, 50, 5).getValues();
var numRows = range.getLastRow()-1;
```

But this does

```
var numRows = mainList.getLastRow()-1;
```

range is CLEARLY a range? So why I am I getting a typeError?

> TypeError: Cannot find function getLastRow in object DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation we can tell that the variable range is actually a 2D array of data from the error, so there is no method `getLastRow()`.  There is a `range.length` however.

```
var range = mainList.getRange(1, 1, 50, 5).getValues();
var numRows = range.getLastRow()-1;
```

It's actually kind of hard to see the value of your second example since we can't tell where mainList came from.  Take a look at [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

If mainList is a spreadsheet then we can go to [the spreadsheet documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)  and in the example [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)) we see that  we can define the range in A1Notation by specifying the name of the sheet( sometimes called tab) as so:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = ss.getRange("Invoices!A1:D4");
```

Personally I usually like to take the time to do something like this:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // or SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid'); I Google Drive the ids are the primary key to locating files not names.  And you can get the id of a spreadsheet right of of the url whenever you open it up.
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheetname');
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,50,5);
var valuesArray = range.getValues();
```

Then you can loop through values array as shown below:

```
for(var i=0;i<valuesArray.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<valuesArray[i].length;j++){
     var cellvalue=valuesArray[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, mainList is the name of the spreadsheet. I should have changed it for the example. Do you know how to declare range so it IS a range not a 2D array?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that all out. I am struggling with arrays vs range objects as I try to make my long slow scripts faster.